# Check Proximity of Point in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have array A. How to code it such that 1st row is compared to 2nd, 2nd to 3rd and 3rd to 4th. If Euclidean distance is less than 1, then it is omitted from array A, otherwise kept in it.

```
A=[ 1.05, 33.43; 1.66, 30.81; 1.78, 30.98; 2.01, 28.05]
A=sortrows(A,[1,2])
for i=size(A,1)
      if (sum(A(i,:)-A(i+1)).^2, 2)<1
          A(i+1,:)=[ ]
      end
end
```

Please suggest correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a diff by using different indexers on the rows of `A`:

```
A = [1.05, 33.43; 1.66, 30.81; 1.78, 30.98; 2.01, 28.05];
A = sortrows(A,[1 2]);

A1 = A(1:end-1,:);
A2 = A(2:end,:);
```

Once this is done, the euclidean distance can be computed in a vectorized way, which performs generally much better than `for` loops in Matlab:

```
D = sqrt(sum((A1 - A2) .^ 2,2));

% this is because the computation is performed on *rows-1*, hence the
% indexation must be adjusted in order to produce the correct result
D = [Inf; D];
```

Finally, only the points with a distance greater than or equal to `1` are preserved:

```
A(D >= 1,:)

ans =
    1.0500   33.4300
    1.6600   30.8100
    2.0100   28.0500
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in the code you've posted:

- in the `for` statement the initia value is missing
- also the termination should end at `size(A,1)-1`
- some brackets are missing in the `if' statement
- the `square root` is missing in the computation the `euclidean distance`
- you should not remove the rows of the initial matrix within the loop

A possible solution could be:

```
A=[ 1.05, 33.43; 1.66, 30.81; 1.78, 30.98; 2.01, 28.05]
A=sortrows(A,[1,2])
% Make a copy of the original matrix
B=A
% Loop over the matrix rows
for i=1:size(A,1)-1
   % Evaluate the Euclidean Distance and store it in an array (for verification purpose)
   ed(i)=sqrt(sum((A(i,:)-A(i+1,:)).^2))
   % If the Euclidean Distance is less than the threshold, delete the row in the
   % B matrix
   if(ed(i) < 1) 
          B(i+1,:)=[]
      end
end
```

This gives:

*Euclidean Distances*

```
ed =

   2.69007   0.20809   2.93901
```

*Original Matrix*

```
A =

    1.0500   33.4300
    1.6600   30.8100
    1.7800   30.9800
    2.0100   28.0500
```

*Updated Matrix*

```
B =

    1.0500   33.4300
    1.6600   30.8100
    2.0100   28.0500
```

The third row of the original matrix has been deleted being the Euclidean Distance equal to `0.20809`.